# In a nuget package, how do I specify a different native assembly depending on .net runtime

Tags: nuget, runtime, native

Depending on the .net runtime, I need a different *native* dll installed with the assembly.
The name of the native dll is the same, regardless of .net runtime.

More details:

Assembly Main, when built for .net 6, requires native assembly csmarty.dll.  When built for .net framework 4.8, it also requires native assembly csmarty.dll, but a different one.  In both cases, the platform is win64, but the .net runtime differs.

Is there a way to build this in nuget so that it installs properly?